# PDO query using func_get_args(); is giving error message

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a function where I can simply do `<?php echo $user_args['user_id']; ?>` to call a variable. If a user is logged in I can use this format. I can't get this function working in PDO though.

#### I'm getting this error message:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/user/func/user.func.php on line 35

    Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/user/func/user.func.php on line 35
```

#### This is the function I'm trying to do:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

function user_args() {

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

        $args = func_get_args();
        $fields = implode(', ', $args);
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id");
        $query->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
        if($query->execute()) {
            $query_success = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($args as $arg) {
                $args[$arg] = stripslashes($query_success[$arg]);
                }
            return $args;
            }

        }

    $user_args = user_args('user_id',
                            'username',
                            'email',
                            'password');

    echo $user_args['user_id']; // <- The function isn't working so I can't do this
```

What's wrong in my code that's making this not work? Thanks!

Comment: You have a scope issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/3933332

Comment: Just pass `user_args($db)` OR use globe inside your function `globe $db;`

Comment: `$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id");` $db is undefined variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$db is missing inside the function

```
function user_args($db) {

       // ...
        }
```

also add $db in the function call:

```
$user_args = user_args($db, 'user_id',
                        'username',
                        'email',
                        'password');
```

Comment: When I do this, it gives me this error: 
Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDO could not be converted to string in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/user/func/user.func.php on line 19

Comment: @Graham, can you write here line 19 of your script?

Comment: $fields = implode(', ', $args);

Comment: insert this line `array_shift($args);` before that line with implode. It will remove first PDO element which is unnecessary there